# validate private variable of another class when giving input

Tags: java

hello I have written code where it takes book details using setter method and displaying details using getter method. When user enters the input it has to enter three details.
**Book Name
Book Price
Author Name**

**I want to check if user has given any negative value or Zero value in Book Price.**
How do I do that? Below is the code. I am practicing Encapsulation problem

```
//Book.java file
class Book
{
    private String bookName;
    private int bookPrice;
    private String authorName;
    public String getBookName()
    {
        return bookName;
    }
    public int getBookPrice()
    {
        return bookPrice;
    }
    public String getAuthorName()
    {
        return authorName;
    }
    public void setBookName(String a)
    {
        bookName=a;
    }
    public void setBookPrice(int b)
    {
        bookPrice=b;
    }
    public void setAuthorName(String c)
    {
        authorName=c;
    }
}
```

```
//TestBook.java file
import java.util.*;
class TestBook
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Book bobj = new Book();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the Book name:");
            bobj.setBookName(sc.nextLine());
            System.out.println("Enter the price:");
            bobj.setBookPrice(sc.nextInt());
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter the Author name:");
            bobj.setAuthorName(sc.nextLine());
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Book Details");
            System.out.println("Book Name :"+bobj.getBookName());
            System.out.println("Book Price :"+bobj.getBookPrice());//should not be -ve or 0
            System.out.println("Author Name :"+bobj.getAuthorName());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put this check in your setter method to check if it is greater than zero. For example:

```
public void setBookPrice(int b)
{
    if(b>0)
       bookPrice=b;
    else
    {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("b must be positive")
     }
}
```

Above code will prevent setting of negative and zero price. You can replace exception throwing code with your own handling.

Answer (score 0):

If you are practising encapsulation I suggest creating a specific validation method for the price so this can be easily modified without changing the public interface.

```
public boolean isValidPrice() {
    return bookPrice > 0;
}
```

This can now be checked with

```
if (!bobj.isValidPrice()) {
    //error handling
}
```

And if the validation rules for price would change the calling code will remain unchaged